# Why is this short Python code using more and more memory?

Tags: python, memory-leaks, screen-scraping

I use this short script to check the price of cat litter of amazon and alert me if it's under 9 bucks. It checks every six hours. The script starts off at 9 MBs but somehow climbs up to 16 over a couple of days.

```
from random import random
from requests import get
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime

def ReadAsin():
    def find_item(text, start, end):
        start_index = text.index(start)
        end_index = text[start_index + len(start):].index(end)
        return text[start_index + len(start):][:end_index]

    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36'}
    AsinList = ['B001N02JXW','B01N9VEMP6']
    # extracted_data = []

    while True:
        for i in AsinList:
            url = "http://www.amazon.de/dp/"+i
            # print("Processing: ",url)
            r = get(url,headers=headers)
            sleep(5 * random())
            try:
                title = ''
                price = find_item(r.text, '<span id="priceblock_ourprice" class="a-size-medium a-color-price">EUR ', '</span>')
                title = find_item(r.text, '<meta name="title" content=', 'Amazon.de')
            except:
                pass
            else:
                price = float(price.replace(',','.'))
                if price < 9:
                    now = datetime.now()
                    print(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),': ',title,'EUR',price)
        sleep(60 * 60 * 6)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ReadAsin()
```

Comment: Does it really matter that it uses 7MB more?

Comment: I suspect is has something to do with `requests`. Check out [this issue](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/4191). It might also just be a consequence of how your OS is reporting the memory usage, i.e., it reports total memory allocated, not total memory being actively used, and it wont reclaim any memory until it has to. Since you aren't doing anything fancy, you could just try using [urllib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request) instead of requests and seeing if that solves your issue.

Comment: also, you could try opening and closing a `requests.Session` object, using a context-manager ideally, so `with requests.Session() as sesh: sesh.get(...)`

Comment: Given the (relatively) small amount of memory you are seeing as in-use, it's possible the runtime just hasn't decided it is worth running the garbage collector yet. Why waste time reclaiming memory that nobody is asking for?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I'd like to not have to ever restart it as it should always run in the background. 7 megs over 2 days means 70 over 20 days, etc. The Raspberry only has so much memory to waste

Comment: @chepner possible. I could just let it run and see if it stops climbing at some point. there are other processes running on the Raspberry, one using abou 200 MBs

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that's reasonably easy to try, thank you! I'll give it another couple of days and then try your suggestions.

Comment: @delica, i mean it may be possible that it is not a linear growth over a longer period.

Comment: @TarunLalwani right, I understand. I'll let it run for a week then and see how it goes. I thought there might be something obviously wrong with the code, and you guys would spot it quickly.

Comment: So, definitely try with `urllib`. It's more painful than `requests`, but isn't too bad in this case. `import urllib.request as request` then `req = request.Request(url, headers=headers)`, then finally, `with request.urlopen(req) as response: r = response.read().decode()`